# Form a edge list from a matrix-python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a matrix which looks like the following:

```
Matrix = [[0,0,1],
          [1,0,1],
          [0,1,0]]
```

I want to form a edge list which looks like the following:

```
Edge_list = {0: [2],
             1: [0, 2],
             2: [1]}
```

The first column in the Edge_list denotes the nodes and next columns denote the nodes to which it has an edge(matrix value of 1).

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want? `[[0, 2], [1, 0, 2], [2, 1]]` / `[[0, [2]], [1, [0, 2]], [2, [1]]]` / `{0: [2], 1: [0, 2], 2: [1]}` / `[[2], [0, 2], [1]]`

Comment: I want it like this:{0: [2], 1: [0, 2], 2: [1]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [dict comprehension](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> matrix = [
...     [0,0,1],
...     [1,0,1],
...     [0,1,0],
... ]
>>>
>>> {i: [j for j, x in enumerate(row) if x] for i, row in enumerate(matrix)}
{0: [2], 1: [0, 2], 2: [1]}
```